# Adding Overlay to OSMDROID

Tags: android, android-maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have been struggling with this long time.
I am trying to add Overlay on my map.
I am using the open source OSMdroid. but all I get by the example is a straight red line from one corner to another. 
My target is to add some icon where my geoPoint is set.

here is my code:

```
 package osmdemo.demo;

import java.util.List;

import microsoft.mappoint.TileSystem;

import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView.Projection;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ScaleBarOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.util.constants.MapViewConstants;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class map extends Activity implements MapViewConstants
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    protected static final String PROVIDER_NAME = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    MapController mapController;
    MapView mapView;
    ScaleBarOverlay mScaleBarOverlay;
    private MapOverlay mmapOverlay = null;
    private LocationManager mLocMgr;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(20);
        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(31.987968, 34.783069);
        mapController.setCenter(point2);

        this.mmapOverlay = new MapOverlay(this);

        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.add(mmapOverlay);
        mapView.invalidate();
    }

    public class MapOverlay extends org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay
    {

        public MapOverlay(Context ctx)
        {
            super(ctx);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected void draw(Canvas pC, MapView pOsmv, boolean shadow)
        {
            if (shadow)
                return;

            Paint lp3;
            lp3 = new Paint();
            lp3.setColor(Color.RED);
            lp3.setAntiAlias(true);
            lp3.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            lp3.setStrokeWidth(1);
            lp3.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            lp3.setTextSize(12);
            // Calculate the half-world size
            final Rect viewportRect = new Rect();
            final Projection projection = pOsmv.getProjection();
            final int zoomLevel = projection.getZoomLevel();
            int mWorldSize_2 = TileSystem.MapSize(zoomLevel) / 2;

            // Save the Mercator coordinates of what is on the screen
            viewportRect.set(projection.getScreenRect());
            // DON'T set offset with either of below
            // viewportRect.offset(-mWorldSize_2, -mWorldSize_2);
            // viewportRect.offset(mWorldSize_2, mWorldSize_2);

            // Draw a line from one corner to the other
            pC.drawLine(viewportRect.left, viewportRect.top,
                    viewportRect.right, viewportRect.bottom, lp3);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0)
        {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
        }

    }

}
```

thats my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.overlay" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application >
        <activity android:name=".OverlayDemo" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance,

ray.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? Are you trying to add an icon at a geopoint? Are you trying to do custom drawing?

Comment: I am trying to add an icon at the geopoint exactly!  !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The jars versions 3.0.3 and 3.0.4 seem to have changed a bit since the sample code was written.

If you are basing your app on the code as quoted in the previous answer, then change the line

```
mResourceProxy = new ResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
mResourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
```

This should at least get you going with a default icon.

**EDIT**

This should centre the map just NE of Liverpool and put an icon just off centre.

```
package osmdemo.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.osmdroid.DefaultResourceProxyImpl;
import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedIconOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayItem;
import org.osmdroid.views.util.constants.MapViewConstants;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DemoMap extends Activity implements LocationListener,
        MapViewConstants {

    private MapView mMapView;
    private MapController mapController;
    private LocationManager mLocMgr;
    private ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> mMyLocationOverlay;
    private ResourceProxy mResourceProxy;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mResourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.copymain);

        mMapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapController = this.mMapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(15);
        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(53554070, -2959520); // centre map here
        GeoPoint point3 = new GeoPoint(53554070 + 1000, -2959520 + 1000); // icon goes here
        mapController.setCenter(point2);
        mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 100,
                this);

        ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        // Put overlay icon a little way from map centre
        items.add(new OverlayItem("Here", "SampleDescription", point3));

        /* OnTapListener for the Markers, shows a simple Toast. */
        this.mMyLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
                new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index,
                            final OverlayItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                DemoMap.this,
                                "Item '" + item.mTitle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true; // We 'handled' this event.
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index,
                            final OverlayItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                DemoMap.this, 
                                "Item '" + item.mTitle ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                }, mResourceProxy);
        this.mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mMyLocationOverlay);
        mMapView.invalidate();
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
        GeoPoint gpt = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
        mapController.setCenter(gpt);
        mMapView.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

}
```

It's a bit rough and ready, but at least it runs OK with just the 3.0.4 jar and the slf4j one. Hope it helps.

**EDIT 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="osmdemo.demo"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="DemoMap"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

.

Comment: Yes, I have changed it to DefaultResousrseProxyImpl but I still get this error: 06-30 15:48:55.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11997): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 15:48:55.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11997): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.overlay/com.test.overlay.OverlayDemo}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.overlay.OverlayDemo in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.test.overlay-2.apk]
...

Comment: Maybe I need to add  more Jars to the build path? Currently I use these ones: APACHEMIME ver:47.0.4, HTTPMIME ver:4.0 beta1, osmdroid3.0.4.jar slf4j ver:1.5.8

Comment: No, I've just got the sl4j and the osmdroid versions that you have. I'll see if I can cut down my code to the bare minimum to show an overlay and post it into my answer.

Comment: Thank you for that, I am struggling days with this!

Comment: Still same error with the ClassNotFoundException. What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe it's your manifest.xml? The package names need to match.

Comment: You were right. thanks:) sometimes u dont pay attention to the old details

Comment: I'm not sure what bits you've renamed but I've got the one class - DemoMap and it's in the package 'osmdemo.demo'. I'll add my manifest to the answer in a minute. I haven't got the . before the activity name though. the dot means something though, I just can't remember what!

Comment: it works.. but question.. when I tried to change to another longtitude,latitude I didnt see the item. those are the lines I changed in your code: GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(32.056516, 34.782367); 
GeoPoint point3 = new GeoPoint(32.056516 + 1000, 34.782367 + 1000);

Comment: Pass the params as ints (in microdegrees) not doubles for this offset to work, e.g. 32056516, 34782367

Comment: Please one more thing. When there is a change in the location the map does change but the Icon is gone. how do i validate the Icon into the new change?

Comment: since these libraries have been suplanted, from osmdroid 4.2 onwards, you must alter `mTitle` for `getTitle()`and `MapController` becomes `IMapController` (from 4.3 onwards, `GeoPoint` becomes `IGeoPoint` also)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add an icon, then you want to look at the ItemizedOverlay classes. You can use osmdroid's ItemizedIconOverlay which is a concrete implementation of ItemizedOverlay, or you can subclass ItemizedOverlay on your own. Take a look at the samples, such as:

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/org/osmdroid/samples/SampleWithMinimapItemizedoverlay.java

Comment: I found that example: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/ItemizedIconOverlay.java?r=887. but I couldn't understand how do I integrate it in my code? how my map will use it inside of it?

Comment: I added a sample to my answer that should help.

Comment: It requires the class ResourceProxyImpl. So I took it from: http://www.google.com/codesearch#OOgMjZrCM0A/trunk/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/org/osmdroid/ResourceProxyImpl.java&q=ResourceProxyImpl%20package:http://osmdroid%5C.googlecode%5C.com.  but I get this error on runtime:  unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.overlay/com.test.overlay.OverlayDemo}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.overlay.OverlayDemo in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.test.overlay-1.apk]  any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@rayman

> Please one more thing. When there is a change in the location the map
>   does change but the Icon is gone. how do i validate the Icon into the
>   new change? – rayman Jul 1 '11 at 7:12

this is where your location changes

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
    GeoPoint gpt = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
    mapController.setCenter(gpt);
    mMapView.invalidate();
}
```

But as you can see it does not add new icon to the overlay.

You should clear the previous items

```
items.clear()
```

(if you want the "old" icon to be removed when the new one is created) and then add the new point (gpt) to the items.

```
items.add(new OverlayItem("Title", "Description", gpt));
```

and so on...