# Add Icon or Image in Map overlays

Tags: java, android, image, overlay, osmdroid

First, I have an offline map integrated into Android but the problems is that the map doesn't have an updated establishments for mapping. What I wanted to do is to to add map overlays that  will contain icons or small images of the establishment with corresponding geocoordinates.

I am using osmdroid library.

Comment: I think that you are looking the same than in this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496366/adding-overylay-to-osmdroid

Answer (score 0):

This is very easily achieved with ItemizedIconOverlay and an array of OverLayItem or a custom descendent.

The OSMdroid sample applications show how these classes are used quite clearly.