# How notify current layer for position change

Tags: java, android, dictionary, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm currently using osmdroid to display current positioning.

Based on the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319094/adding-overlay-to-a-mapview-in-osmdroid) i tried to optimize the system a little bit by not constructing the `ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>` and `ArrayList<OverlayItem>` each time my location is changed, but construct them only once in the constructor, and later on simply add points to my ArrayList variable.

Here's how it looks now:

```
private void InitializeMarkersOverlay() {
    mOverlayItemArrayList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> locationOverlay =
            new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(this, mOverlayItemArrayList, null);

    mMapView.getOverlays().add(locationOverlay);
}
```

and when a new location arrives:

```
private void AddPointToOverlay(GeoPoint gPt, boolean bShouldClearList) {

    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem("", "", gPt);
    Drawable markerDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.pin);
    overlayItem.setMarker(markerDrawable);

    // first time initializer
    if(bShouldClearList) {
        mOverlayItemArrayList.clear();
    }
    mOverlayItemArrayList.add(overlayItem);
}
```

Since my `mMapView` already has a pointer to `mOverlayItemArrayList` i was hoping that my mapview's layer would be automatically notified regarding the change. but nothing actually happens. Only by recreating the objects, i get to see the pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by accessing the overlay directly from the mapview object, not sure why exactly, as i was hoping `mMapView.getOverlays()` would hold a **reference** to the ItemizedIconOverlay and its itimized array

```
if(mMapView.getOverlays().size() > 0) {
            ((ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>)mMapView.getOverlays().get(0)).removeAllItems();
            ((ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>)mMapView.getOverlays().get(0)).addItem(overlayItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your assumption about references is correct. Real reason is that you used addItem method on ItemizedIconOverlay instance. See my response for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the list does not work because ItemizedIconOverlay need to do some operations on addition. You can check source code for [ItemizedIconOverlay](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/ItemizedIconOverlay.java).

You can see there is call to populate() in addItem method (and all other methods which are manipulating with items).

```
public boolean addItem(final Item item) {
    final boolean result = mItemList.add(item);
    populate();
    return result;
}
```

But populate() is an implementation detail and is marked as protected so you cannot call it directly.

Correct solution would be:

1. Don't keep reference to the list but to ItemizedIconOverlay
   instance.
2. Use mLocationOverlay.addItem(overlayItem)
3. You may need to call mapView.invalidate() after adding new point.